# Can a single product detail page appear on the same page as the product list instead?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm tasked with using react to create our online store. So far I've succesfully called our products using the data from the API we're developing, and I've also been able to pass the data from the mapped product list to a single product page using a link.

Only issue now is that we'd like the single product to appear on the same page as the product list when it's clicked on by the user, perhaps as a component that appears above the product list (as opposed to linking to a separate page). For the life of me I cannot seem to find a method of doing this that doesn't result in an error or the app reading parameters as undefined. Admitedly, I am quite new to React, so it's possible I'm missing something very obvious.

**This is the ProductList.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SingleProduct from './SingleProduct';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const API_URL = "http://exampleapiurl/ExampleCollection/Examplecollectionid";

const Products = () => {
    
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts().then((products) => setProducts(products))
    }, []);

    const getProducts = () =>
        fetch(API_URL)
            .then((res) => res.json());

   // OnClick Handler
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        
        setIsShown(current => !current);
    };

    return (

        <div className="GetProducts">
           <h1> Fetch Products from a Collection </h1>
            
                <div className="container">
                <div className="row">

                    {/* ️ Ideally, we'd like the single product item to appear here on button click, as opposed to a separate page */}
                    {
                        isShown && 
                        <SingleProduct/>     
                    }

                    {products.map((frame) => (
                        <div>
                            {/* ️ Current link to separate page for product*/}
                            <Link to={`/SingleProduct/${frame.frameId}`}>
                             
                              {/* ️ Button to show single item on same page as product list.*/}
                            <button onClick={handleClick} value={frame.frameId} > View {frame.frameName}</button>

                                <div key={frame.frameId}>
                                    <img src={`https://exampleimageurl/${frame.thumnail}`} />
                                    <li>Frame Name: {frame.frameName}</li>
                                    <li>Gender: {frame.gender}</li>
                            </div>

                            </Link>
 
                        </div>
                    ))
                    }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Products;
```

**This is the SingleProduct.js**

```
class SingleProduct extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
               isLoading: false,
                item: [],
                frameId: this.props.match.params.frameId
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {

            this.setState({ isLoading: true });
            fetch(`http://exampleapiurl/${this.state.frameId}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.setState({
                        item: json,
                        isLoading: false
                    })
                })
        }

        render() {
            
            const { item } = this.state;
            return (
                
                this.state.isLoading ?
                    (<h1>Loading {this.state.frameId}...</h1>)
                    :
                    (
                        <div>
                            
                            <div className="col border text-center" key={item.frameId}>
                                <img src={`https://exampleimageurl/${item.framePic}`} />
                                <li>Frame Name: {item.frameName}</li>
                                <li>Gender: {item.gender}</li>
                               
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    )
                    
            )
        }
    }

    export default SingleProduct
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import Products from './components/ProductList';
import SingleProduct from './components/SingleProduct';


export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/ProductList' component={Products} />
                <Route path='/SingleProduct/:frameId' component={SingleProduct} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include all the relevant code like the routes for these pages/components that you want to render? See [mcve].

Comment: Added the routes

Comment: You can either move `SingleProduct` (*and associated value(s)*) into the `Product` component to be conditionally rendered, or move the `SingleProduct` route into `Product` to be rendered as a descendent route. For option 2 you'd need to make the parent product route `path="/ProductList/*"` and tweak the descendent path relative to this parent path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you don't want to use route for passing the data instead of that you can then pass props to the `SingleProduct` component.

With props getting passed it should look

```
 {
    isShown && 
    <SingleProduct frameId = {selectedFrameId}/>     
 }
```

Declare a new state variable to store the selected frameid

```
const [selectedFrameId, setSelectedFrameId] = useState<Number>();
```

Your onclick event will need adjustment, because you will need to pass the frameid in `map` function.

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(frame.frameId)}
```

and then set the state via `handleClick` event

```
const handleClick = (frameId) => {            
      setIsShown(current => !current);
      setSelectedFrameId(frameId);
};
```

With this in your `SingleProduct` component the fetch call can directly use the `props(frameid)`

```
fetch(`http://exampleapiurl/${this.props.frameId}`)
```

Also I would recommend to change `SingleProduct` to a functional component instead of class component.